# How to get Visual Studio to support Doxygen style comments like XML doc?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, doxygen

Visual Studio will recognize XML documentation and helpfully display tooltips in the editor based on it. Is there any way (I'm thinking an extension or similar) to get this same functionality from the Doxygen comments?

There is far too much code to move over to XML documentation.